# Python - Fitting a parameter defined curve to another fixed curve

Tags: python, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

This is a problem which might be explained better through images than anything else.

The curve in red is fixed - this is a result of a simulation.

The dashed lines are generated from an analytic solution which is generated with a known functional form; there is a parameter within this which alters the positions of the peaks, this d_eff parameter.

In summary - I would like to find the optimal value for this parameter (and the corresponding error in it), such that I get good agreement between the positions of the peaks (amplitude is not so important here). To clarify; I am **not finding the polynomial that best fits the data** - I am looking to find the optimal value of the parameter d_eff into the analytic function that best fits this data

I am open to considering fitting over the entire data range, or a small subset (e.g. only the first peak) - one can easily slice the useful region.

I know by inspection that this value should be approximately 2.2 (see green line, where there is good agreement between positions of 1st and 2nd peaks), but I would like to find an optimal value for this in terms of positions of the peaks. Optimal in this case means that I have good agreement between the first peak (amplitude is not so important in this case). I have tried using `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` but this is not so clear how one fits a curve to another curve. Other methods that come to mind involve Fourier transforms, but I wonder if there is a clear and intuitive method that one might adopt for this problem?

Thanks in advance - please see figure below.

[image: My figure in question.]

Comment: I would have thought curve fit or least squares would yeild an acceptable solution, with the fixed data as the y, x as x, your function generating the analytical solution as f and 2.2 as p0?

Comment: @Joseph unfortunately it does not; I've tried to do that but the function generating the analytic solution is not just a trivial function in the form for curve_fit sadly. I'm resorting to some manual least-squares method myself, but results are sketchy at the minute!

Comment: @Mr.T indeed, this is a vague question; perhaps it's just been poorly explained. No polynomial should have the fit; the idea is about optimising a parameter rather than finding a polynomial fit, as mentioned above

Comment: That's a shame, maybe as you say fitting a small region is the way to go. If the analytical function and fixed curve are always the same form (as shown in the image) maybe this could be reduced to a linear fitting problem? e.g. take the max of both functions, 8 peaks p1 - p8. So you have fixed p1-8 and analytical function p1-8 (maybe drop p4 and p7 with the discontinuties). Then find the param value which maximises the correlation between the pairs of points (peaks). Then do the same with the minimums and take the value that maximises both? maybe this is oversimplying the problem

Comment: @Joseph that's a really nice idea, and is actually quite similar to my current approach funnily enough! Also very close to my grand goal for this research but that's unrelated. I think perhaps the amplitude discrepancy problem is causing an issue for this also - I'll look into simplifying this into a linear problem since then I can rely on premade packages rather than my own subpar understanding of how to apply LSQ methods. Thanks for your helpful comments.

Comment: glad it was useful, good luck with this problem and your research!